# PHP after uploading image shows error "mysql extension is deprecated"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have successfully uploaded a image in MYSQL, however after the image is uploaded i get the below error.

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in x:\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\upload.php on line 6
>   done

```
if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    mysql_select_db ("test");
    $imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
    $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO output_images(imageType ,imageData)
    VALUES('{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}')";
    $current_id = mysql_query($sql) or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Image Insert<br/>" . mysql_error());
    if(isset($current_id)) {
        echo "done";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it is basically telling you what it is telling you. `mysql_*` API will be removed from future releases of PHP. As it were, you stand to gain by learning alternatives (like the suggested PDO api). There are very good security reasons for retiring the `mysql_` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using a version of PHP that does not support mysql_* functions, instead you need use the mysqli_* functions. (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php)

Your code will looks like this:

```
if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
    mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    mysqli_select_db ("test");
    $imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
    $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO output_images(imageType ,imageData)
    VALUES('{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}')";
    $current_id = mysqli_query($sql) or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Image Insert<br/>" . mysqli_error());
    if(isset($current_id)) {
        echo "done";
    }
}
}
```

My personal recommendation is use PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)